# Mutators ignored when model saved

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model that stores decimals as integers that are supposed to be converted when read/written from the database using mutators:

```
public function getPrice($value)
{
    return $value / 100;
}

public function setPrice($value)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = round($value, 2) * 100;
}
```

However, the mutators are never called.

For instance, if I do `create/insert/save` etc:

```
PriceHistory::create(['price' => 1234.25]);
```

I get this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22P02]:
    Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:
        invalid input syntax for integer:
            "1234.25" (SQL: insert into "price_history" ("price") values (1234.25))'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs:

> **Defining An Accessor**
>
> To define an accessor, create a **get**Foo**Attribute** method on your model
>   where Foo is the "camel" cased name of the column you wish to access.

So, it would be like this:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($value)
{
    return $value / 100;
}

public function setPriceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = round($value, 2) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the accessor/mutator needs to have `Attribute` in it, just like [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators). Give this a go:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($value)
{
    return $value / 100;
}

public function setPriceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['price'] = round($value, 2) * 100;
}
```